# While taking multiple input error is occuring

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am getting this error:
The method:

```
addInputPath(Job, Path, Class<? extends InputFormat>, Class<? extends Mapper>)
```

in the type `MultipleInputs` is 
 not applicable for the arguments `(JobConf, Path, Class<TextInputFormat>, Class<App.MapClass>)`

for following code:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, in, TextInputFormat.class, MapClass.class);
/* ------------------------ */

package hadoop.mi4;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;


public class App {

    public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(itr.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class TokenizerMapper1 extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(itr.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
            }
            result.set(sum);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: App <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
         }
         Job job = new Job(conf, "word count");
         job.setJarByClass(App.class);
         job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
         job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
         job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
         job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
         job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
         //FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
         MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]), TextInputFormat.class, TokenizerMapper.class);
         MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]), TextInputFormat.class, TokenizerMapper1.class);
         FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[2]));
         System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: how would we know what is `job, in` show us your code

Comment: in MultipleInputs.addInputPath i am getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you've mixed up classes from `mapred` with `mapreduce`. Replace the following import

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
```

with

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat
```

Comment: Now the import becomes error.
Is there any extra thing needs to be added in POM.XML file for executing multiplefiles

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my import. You can try now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `job` variable is of type `JobConf` whereas it should be a `Job`. You should try

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(new Job(job), in, TextInputFormat.class, MapClass.class);
```

you should also check that `MapClass` extends `Mapper`.

Comment: MultipleInputs.addInputPath(new Job(job), in, TextInputFormat.class, MapClass.class);
Now i had written it in your format now it is giving another error:-     

The method addInputPath(Job, Path, Class<? extends InputFormat>, Class<? extends Mapper>) in the type MultipleInputs is 
 not applicable for the arguments (Job, Path, Class<TextInputFormat>, Class<App.MapClass>)

Comment: @ujjwalkotdiya ok, I have updated my answer. Can you show `MapClass` code? Does it extend `Mapper`?

Comment: it does not extend mapper but implements it.
The mapper is same as that of wordcount.
The whole example is same as that of wordcount but i am just taking input from two files

Comment: @ujjwalkotdiya `Mapper` is a class, not an interface, so how can `App.MapClass` implement `Mapper`? Show us more code.